# MYSQL query for searching name and neglect Vowels in it

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a simple query for searching name in mysql database..

```
SELECT name from tbl_name where name = '$name';
```

i want that the result must neglect vowels for eg...  if i search for preeti keyword it must show result for Priti also... Vowels must be neglected in result...

please help me to do this... thanks

Comment: (in PHP) `$name = preg_replace('/[aeiouy]/i','',$name);` `i` tells to be case-insensitive. Assuming your DB contains 'stripped' values. If you want to keep track to the number of letters preeti <> preti replace with `'_'` instead of `''` `$name = preg_replace('/[aeiouy]/i','_',$name);` also use `LIKE` in your query

Answer (score 0):

You could do a regex replacement on both sides of the comparison to strip vowels:

```
SELECT name
FROM tbl_name
WHERE REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '[aeiou]', '', 1, 0, 'i') =
          REGEXP_REPLACE('Preeti', '[aeiou]', '', 1, 0, 'i');
```

For the RHS of the comparison, you could also just ensure that you input only consonants.  That is, if calling this query from your application, you might end up running directly:

```
SELECT name
FROM tbl_name
WHERE REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '[aeiou]', '', 1, 0, 'i') = 'Prt';
```

The above answer should work on MySQL 8+.  You could try a similar approach using nested calls to `REPLACE` on earlier versions of MySQL, but it would be ugly.

Comment: this will work only for Preeti word.. what about other words.. its should work for words like searching for anureet gives result for Anurit also... it must be work for dynamic words also

Comment: No...this works for _all_ words, just use the first query.

Comment: any query for Mysql 5.6 ?

Comment: @bharat Again, did you read my answer?  I mention that you may do a series of replacements to remove all vowels from the LHS/RHS before comparing, and then do the comparison.